# Send a variable from php to js ajax

Tags: javascript, php, post

i need to send a variable with post in php to js and in the js get it with ajax, the value of the  variable is a string.
In php i get the value like this

> $_POST["secret"] = json_decode($oSecret->seeSecret());

And in javascript i am trying this

> $.post("usuariosService.php",function(datos){
>                   alert(datos);
>               },"json");

but i dont get anything, can somebody help me?

Comment: Where do you get the $oSecret->seeSecret() from?

Comment: From a class that makes a query to mysql.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the concept of ajax. You want to send value from php to javascript with $_POST["secret"] = json_decode($oSecret->seeSecret());?

Comment: Echo `echo json_decode($oSecret->seeSecret());`

Comment: All i want to do is send the value of the string from the php to the javascript, the problem is that the value is supposed that cant be seen from the inspector, so i have to send it with post i think

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example to demonstrate how to put a PHP variable's value into a JS variable:

```
<?php
$secret = 'secretHashValue';
?>

<script>
let secret = '<?= $secret ?>';
console.log(secret);
</script>
```

Please note that this code needs to be in a .php file. You cannot use this within a JS file, because JS files will be delivered as static files and therefore will not be interpreted as PHP code by the webserver.

---

I've composed a small example using a form to POST something. Just create these two files and then open /form.php in your browser.

form.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="/posted.php">
        <input type="text" name="postedValue">
        <button>Post this value</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

posted.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $postedValue = $_POST['postedValue'];
    ?>

    <script>
    let postedValue = '<?= $postedValue ?>';
    alert('Posted value: ' + postedValue);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this makes things a little clearer.

Comment: I must send the value from the php using post method, and get it in the javascript file using ajax, I have tried this but my teacher says its not valid for him, thanks anyway

Comment: That's weird, there are no ways of posting values from a server langauge (php) to clientside language (javascript) (even if a solution exists that I do not know if, it shouldn't exist because it's simply wrong!) Tell your teacher to rethink the task!

Comment: Wolfgangs solution here is the "way to go". Just note that <?= probably must be replaced with <?php echo $secret;?>

Comment: @PabloLópez I've edited my answer and added an example that you can try yourself. Please let me know if this helps.